# How can save the audio file as new one every time I play the tts?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

My code for creating **`test.wav`** file which is being overwritten every time I type a text inside `sdcard/Android folder`. I want to save each file with name when I type.

```
 play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             speakOut();
             speakTextTxt=text.getText().toString();

             destinationFileName = "/sdcard/Android/test.wav";
             myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,speakTextTxt);
             mTts.synthesizeToFile(speakTextTxt, myHashRender, destinationFileName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change file name for each entry 
e.g

```
    destinationFileName = "/sdcard/Android",System.currentTimeMillis()+".wav";
```

Comment: Thanks Its working fine but a fraction of change needed destinationFileName = "/sdcard/Android/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".wav";

Comment: can you please tell me how can I save files with name ? It is quite hard to find typed text later from random numbers as name .

Comment: then just append text with fraction like someText+System.currentTimeMillis()+".wav"

Comment: Ok bro I'll try and let u know